# Average quantity over Keplerian orbit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, mathematical-physics, orbital-motion

I have been working through some lecture notes and am quite confused on something. I am trying to understand how to average a quantity over an orbit (Keplerian) but I am struggling to get a clear idea on this.
The notes I am using is: http://www.sns.ias.edu/sites/default/files/isima1.pdf

So I am trying to do the exercise on page 8, but have no idea how to get the solutions shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time average of a periodic quantity $Q(t)$ is, by definition,

$$\langle Q \rangle=\frac{1}{T}\int_0^TQ(t)\,dt$$

where $T$ is the period.

For Keplerian orbits, it is usually easiest to change the integration variable to the angular coordinate $\psi$ and express all quantities being integrated in terms of $\psi$.

The exercise thus consists of doing a variety of angular integrals. There is a typo in one of the results.

Comment: thanks for this. I have tried to use this in solving the integral but I yield answers. Could you please go through an example question (question 1 for example)?
I am also using r = a(1-e^2)/( 1 + e cos(phi) )

Comment: Complete solutions to homework-like exercises aren’t allowed on this site. What problem are you running into? You have the correct $r$. Do you know how to change the variable of integration from $t$ to $\psi$? You need to make use of (12).

Comment: I am actually having an issue with the resulting integral. Take question 2 as an example, I end up with an integral that I am struggling to solve.

Comment: The integrals with powers of $1+e\cos\psi$ in the denominator are difficult, although *Mathematica* can do them. I know of two ways to do them without a computer. One is to turn the integral into a contour integral around the unit circle in the complex plane, and use the residue theorem. The other is to expand in powers of $e$, integrate term-by-term, and then try to recognize what function of $e$ the resulting infinite series is. If you are only having a problem doing integrals, ask on Math SE.

Comment: I used *Mathematica* to check all the results. The first answer should have a + rather than a -.

Comment: If you ask on Math SE, let me know *here* in a comment and if no one else answers there I will.

Comment: I have asked the question on Maths SE, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3673800/solving-orbit-average-integrals

Comment: I doubt that a physics question involving nine different time averages over Keplerian orbits will go over well there. You need to show the exact integral you're having trouble with, since it is a *math* site. You told me that you “end up with an integral” for question 2, so show it there. If you have not actually figured out what to integrate, explain here what problem you are having doing so. Setting up the integral involves physics; doing the integral is just math.

Comment: Your question on Math SE got closed because they didn’t see any math there.

Comment: I have re-posted the integral I am having trouble with, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3674256/difficult-definite-integrals